# Colocando cifrão em um input no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em Laravel e preciso de uma ajuda nesse trecho de código, como coloco para aparecer o cifrão "R$" nesse trecho?

```
< input name="valor_entrada" required id="valor_entrada"  value="{{$crediarios -> valor_compra}}" type="number" min="1" step="any" class="form-control"></div>
```

Esse e um IMPUT que traz o valor do banco de dados, um valor de compra de um produto, só que quando trago essa informação ela vem em um numero como por exemplo 144.5, gostaria de saber se existe uma forma nesse pequeno trecho que mandei acima de colocar para vim junto com o R$ eu sou iniciante em programação estou com dificuldades nisso.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Não seria só colocar no input? `value="R${{$crediarios -> valor_compra}}" `

Answer (score 0):

Como o amigo falou, usar `value="R${{$crediarios -> valor_compra}}"` resolve. Porém, se esse dado for enviado novamente no form, você precisará tratar o R$ antes de salvar no banco.

Sugestão:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/5.0.6/jquery.inputmask.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#valor_entrada").inputmask('decimal', {
                    'alias': 'numeric',
                    'groupSeparator': ',',
                    'autoGroup': true,
                    'digits': 2,
                    'radixPoint': ".",
                    'digitsOptional': false,
                    'allowMinus': false,
                    'prefix': 'R$ ',
                    'placeholder': ''
        });
    });
</script>
```